# I can't edit a memory address in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I don't really know how to phrase the title, what I want is to edit the string in one pointer from another overlapping pointer.

What I want to obtain in this code what  is `1abcd abcd` but what I get instead is `123 abcd`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char* x = (char*)malloc(4);
    x = "123";
    char*  y = (char*) x+1;
    y = "abcd";
    printf("%s %s",x,y);

}
```

Comment: You allocate memory for `x`. Then you throw that memory away, and point `x` at a string literal. You point `y` at the `2` in the string literal. Then you point `y` at a different string literal. In effect, the code is `char *x = "123";` followed by `char *y = "abcd";` followed by the `printf`.

Comment: The code as written is equivalent to `printf("%s %s", "123", "abcd");` except there is also a memory leak from a `malloc` allocation without a matching `free`.

Comment: @user3386109 Of course! I forgot to use `strcpy()`. That solved it. I feel very dumb now.

Comment: I hope you have not just changed to use `strcpy` to copy `abcd` into `y` as there is not enough allocated memory for that string to fit.

Comment: I might have... 
But it worked just fine, did I mess some data in some other place on  memory?

Comment: regarding: `char* x = (char*)malloc(4);
    x = "123";`  This overlays the pointer from the call to `malloc()` with a pointer to the literal: `"123"  The result is an unrecoverable memory leak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you assign to `y`, then you assign to `y` again.

```
char *y = x+1;  // first assignment
y = "abcd";              // second assignment
```

`y = "abcd";` isn't a copy. It's assigning a pointer to the `const char[5]` string `abcd` to `y`.

Similar problem here.

```
char *x = malloc(4);
x = "123";
```

`x` is first assigned to the memory from `malloc`, but then overwritten by the `const char[4]` `123`. The `malloc` memory is leaked.

If you want to copy into the memory pointed to by `x` you need to use `strcpy`. However, `x` only has 4 bytes. You'll need more.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    // Allocate memory
    char *x = malloc(6);

    // Copy "123" the heap memory pointed to by x.
    strcpy(x, "123");

    // Assign a pointer to x+1 to y.
    char *y = x+1;

    // Copy "abcd" to the heap memory pointed to by y.
    strcpy(y, "abcd");

    // x='1abcd' y='abcd'
    printf("x='%s' y='%s'\n",x,y);
}
```

Note that `strcpy` is not safe to use when the length of the source and destination strings are not known.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When you say `strcpy` is not safe you mean as in it can be vulnerable?

Comment: @OriónGonzález C doesn't know how much memory is allocated to `x` or `y`. `strcpy` will copy as much as you give it without regard for how much memory is allocated in the destination. `strcpy(y, "abcd")` is safe because it's a fixed 5 bytes and I know `y` has 5 bytes allocated. `strcpy(y, "abcdef")` will try to write past the allocated 5 bytes. Instead, use length-limited functions like the C11 `strcpy_s` (s for "safe") to explicitly limit how much can be copied. `strcpy_s(y, 5, some_string_of_dubious_size)` or the non-standard `strlcpy`.